# The message like cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram.ext' was shown while I was running my program. What should I do to solve this problem?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

The message cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram.ext' was shown on the screen while I run my program. What should I do?

It happened while I was installed the python-telegram-bot library also telegram library. Can everyone to answer me, please . Thank you ☺️

Answer (score 1):

The `telegram.ext` package has no class called `Chat`. The `telegram` package does, though: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.chat.html.

Please also not that https://pypi.org/project/telegram has nothing to do with https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/ and installing both libraries will lead to problems. I recomment to uninstall `telegram` before reinstalling `python-telegram-bot`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.